# vercel deployment .env not found

Tags: vercel

I am doing a deployment in vercel. Currently change in `scripts` the settings for npm start and add npm run start:staging since I have 2 environments. Add the variables inside vercel and modify the build commands
`env-cmd -f .env.staging react-scripts build` and the development command a: `env-cmd -f .env.staging react-scripts start`. The package.json file looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd -f .env.development react-scripts start",
    "start:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging react-scripts start",
    "start:production": "env-cmd -f .env.production react-scripts start",
    "build": "env-cmd -f .env.development react-scripts build",
    "build:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging react-scripts build",
    "build:production": "env-cmd -f .env.production react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

However it gives me the error in the deployment:

```
Error: Failed to find .env file at path: .env.staging
    at getEnvFile (/vercel/path0/node_modules/env-cmd/dist/get-env-vars.js:40:19)
Error: Command "env-cmd -f .env.staging react-scripts build" exited with 1
```

Obviously this started to happen when the files

- .env.staging
- .env.development

they were pushed to the repository and I removed them from the cache because `.gitignore` was not preventing their upload. What could be happening?

Comment: If the `.env.staging` file isn't in the repo, how is the deployment supposed to use it?

Comment: hi @Phil It's that I had removed them, I thought that the .env should not go inside a repo, I will upload them again, thanks for the quick response

Comment: @Richi .env files are not supposed to go inside your repo! Especially if they contain secrets.

Comment: Hi, yes I have to reenvié de docs from vercel to see how I can resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

Taking into consideration that you don't have the `.env` files in your repo (which you shouldn't ([source](https://ngangasn.com/commit-env-files-to-git-repository/#:%7E:text=env%20file%20contains%20important%20information,are%20using%20in%20your%20application.))) - Vercel can't read them.

You need to specify the Environment Variables specific to deployments.

[How do I set up a staging environment on Vercel?](https://vercel.com/guides/set-up-a-staging-environment-on-vercel)

#### Edit

I suggest reading the [Environment Variables](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables#environments) article on the Vercel Docs if you want to learn more.

Comment: Hi thanks, I will look the docs to see if I can reach a solution

Comment: hi the envs variables were added to vercel before the configuration